# Hosting for a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: hosting, ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I am a Ruby on Rails developer and I am planning to purchase an hosting space in order to publish my web application (I'm developing a small Social Network). This is my first time that I try to deploy a Ruby on Rails application, so I am not expert on the matter.

I would like to find a "compromise" between performance and price. I think that for now a shared server it is enough (maybe) for my needs (suggestions are appreciated...).

In localhost I am using

- Ruby on Rails 3.0.9
- ruby-1.9.2-p136
- Apache
- Phusion Passenger
- MySql

so the hosting server should satisfy the above requisites.

More: in my application I am using the Paperclip gem so another requisite should be Image-Magick.

What hosting service do you advice for my needs? What should I have to care when I purchase a hosting space for RoR? And, most importantly, which hosting service do you advice?

P.S.: if you need some other information just ask and I will update the question.

Comment: We don't do shopping questions here.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/292013/good-sites-for-discussing-specific-hosting-provider-server-specification-scenario for places that are suitable for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you think about aws ec2 and small instance?
For start it should be the best solution.
Instances: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/
Pricing: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

What more.. you have access to root (you are owner of this instance :), so you can install what you want.